# Запуск Python скриптов на Apache2: mod_python или mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, apache

Нужно запустить файлы *.py* на *Apache2*. Пробовал настроить *CGI* - выдавало *"Internal Server Error"*. Максимум, что смог сделать, - содержимое *.py* файла в браузере отобразить как текст.

Хотелось бы написать легкий сайт и залить его на тестовый хостинг. Столкнулся и с тем, что *Python* без каких-то `mod_python` или `mod_wsgi` не работает. Устанавливал `mod_python`, но не знал как настроить.

Использую Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Apache 2, Python 3.4.0.

Comment: «выдавало Internal Server Error» — так надо логи читать.

Comment: есть вообще нормальная инструкция где настраивается апач для питона?

Comment: @FuadIbrahimov, http://djbook.ru/examples/3/

Comment: *питон без каких то mod_python или mod_wsgi не работает* — грубо говоря, в абстрактном *http-сервере* «ничего не работает» — он предназначен для отдачи содержимого файлов (в первую очередь  *html-файлов*), а запуск программ, интерпретаторов — это всего лишь **дополнительная** функциональность. в *apache* она реализована с помощью специализированных модулей.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin понятно.и что вы можете мне посоветовать в такой ситуации?mod_python или mod_wsgi?

Comment: я думаю, в первую очередь это зависит от того, **что** вы планируете реализовать своими скриптами. *mod_python*, насколько я понимаю, это просто «скрипт отработал, результат возвращён в виде *html-страницы*», всеми деталями взаимодействия с клиентом занимается *apache*. а механизм **wsgi** — это «почти» *http-сервер*, с максимально возможным контролем (со стороны *wsgi-программы*) над обработкой запроса и возвратом ответа.

Comment: поправка: «механизм **wsgi**» следует читать как «механизм `cgi` (частный случай — `wsgi`)». а «со стороны *wsgi-программы*» следует читать как «со стороны *cgi-программы*».

Comment: спасибо большое.попробую настроить wsgi ..по результатам отпишусь..

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, WSGI - не является частным случаем CGI. Это два независимых, полностью отличающихся друг от друга интерфейса.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, я не о конкретной реализации говорил, а о *механизме* (взаимодействия). с этой точки зрения (да и с исторической), *wsgi*, насколько я знаю, — это лишь частный случай **механизма** cgi.

Comment: Нет, механизмы (взаимодейстия) cgi и wsgi принципиально отличаются, полностью.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, `CGI` - просто черный ящик, в который пробрасывается запрос от клиента, тот полностью генерирует ответ, и ответ пробрасывается обратно клиенту. В CGI нет общего состояния - приложение запускается для обработки запроса, и умирает сразу-же после выдачи ответа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в случае же с `WSGI` - приложение запускается при первом запросе, проходит инициализацию, и работает грубо говоря до момента прекращения работы веб-сервера. Для обработки запросов просто запускается соответствующий метод приложения. У приложения есть общее состояние между запросами. Приложение может включать в себя middleware, что позволяет как угодно управлять запросами и ответами на них - это позволяет, к примеру, управлять маршрутизацией(не нужно задавать url-rewrite'ы настройками веб-сервера), производить балансировку нагрузки, выполнять пре- и постпроцессинг.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, спасибо за дополнительную информацию. насколько я знаю, спецификациями *cgi* перечисленное вами не оговаривается, но примерно так (обычно) и реализовывается на стороне *cgi-клиента*.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, *cgi-приложение запускается для обработки запроса, и умирает сразу-же после выдачи ответа* — это, насколько я знаю, неверно в общем случае, ведь *cgi-клиент* при взаимодействии, например, через *socket*, просто «обязан» работать постоянно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, `cgi-клиент` - это `веб-сервер`. Да, на стороне веб-серверов существуют "костыли", позволяющие реализовать ту-же маршрутизацию, но принцип и механизмы здесь полностью другие.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, *cgi-клиент - это веб-сервер*, да, прошу прощения, тут я оговорился. речь была о *вызываемой* стороне.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25909/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-sergey-rufanov).

Comment: Если Вы повторно задаёте *тот же самый* вопрос, и хотите добавить новую информацию, то редактируйте его по месту вместо удаления и создания нового вопроса повторно (чтобы было видно старые комментарии). Чтобы начать разработку веб-приложения, Вам не нужен  apache2, у `python` есть http,cgi, wsgi серверы прямо в стандартной библиотеке—для разработки и тестирования их можно использовать—когда  будет готовое оттестированное веб-приложение, можно подумать о том [как его развёртывать](http://www.fullstackpython.com/deployment.html) (веб-сервер (Apache2) является всего лишь небольшой частью).

Comment: как не нужен апач?не лучше сразу разрешить эту проблему?на хостинге что я буду делать с встроенным сервером питона?)

Comment: @FuadIbrahimov: Не лучше. Вы элементарных вещей не знаете (это нормально, просто на этой стадии настраивать apache это пустая трата времени). Начинать надо с того **что** хочется сделать (например: создать веб-сервис для поддержки мобильного приложения, которое по фотографии человека ищет картину (портрет), наиболее похожую на фото), а потом **как** это сделать и в последную очередь **где** это развернуть (на некоторых хостингах , Вы просто `git push` своего wsgi-приложения делаете, а какой там за кадром по умолчанию сервер используется nginx+gunicorn или apache+mod_wsgi -- не важно).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### mod_python `hello world`

в репозитории *ubuntu 14.04*, к сожалению, есть пакет с модулем только для *python 2.**

1. необходимо установить пакет *libapache2-mod-python*:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
   ```
2. в конфигурации дефолтного *virtualhost-а* добавьте, если её нет, секцию *directory* (путь здесь взят из дефолтной конфигурации) и впишите в неё три директивы:

   ```
   <directory /var/www/html>
     addhandler mod_python .py
     pythonhandler hello
     pythondebug on
   </directory>
   ```
3. создайте файл `/var/www/html/hello.py` следующего минимального содержания:

   ```
   import sys

   from mod_python import apache

   def handler(req):
     req.content_type = 'text/plain'
     req.write("hello world! " + sys.version)
     return apache.OK
   ```
4. перезапустите *apache*

   ```
   $ sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
5. запустите скрипт gui-браузером, или консольным, например, *curl-ом*:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost/test.py
   hello world! 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27) 
   [GCC 4.8.2]
   ```

### mod_wsgi `hello world`

в репозитории есть пакет и для *python 3*

1. установите пакет с модулем:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
   ```
2. в конфигурации дефолтного *virtualhost-а* добавьте строку, предварительно закомментировав (если есть) все секции *directory*:

   ```
   wsgiscriptalias / /var/www/html/hello.wsgi
   ```
3. создайте файл `/var/www/html/hello.wsgi` такого содержания:

   ```
   import sys

   def application(environ, start_response):
     status = '200 OK'
     output = 'hello world from wsgi! ' + sys.version

     response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                         ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
     start_response(status, response_headers)

     return [output]
   ```
4. отключите модуль `mod-python` — [вместе они работать не будут](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=656233):

   ```
   $ sudo a2dismod python
   ```
5. перезапустите *apache*:

   ```
   $ sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
6. запустите скрипт gui-браузером, или консольным, например, *curl-ом*:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost/
   hello world from wsgi! 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:24:19) 
   [GCC 4.8.2]
   ```

Comment: `                                                                                                                `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.`

Comment: вот это выдает после первой стадии установки mod_wsgi и апач не запускается

Comment: *Address already in use* — кто-то слушает этот порт. вероятно, неубитые процессы *apache-а*. убейте их: `sudo pkill -KILL apache2` и рестартуйте сервис.

Comment: вроде все заработало.тоесть выдал тот же ответ что вы написали.только почему то ничего не выводится из index.py хоть я и ввел pytest/index.py и написал там print("Hello")

Comment: а вы не обратили внимания, что минимальные примеры отнюдь не сводятся к команде print? это же не зря. и, к тому же, имя файла-обработчика указывается в конфигурации http-сервера. обратитесь, пожалуйста, к документации.

Comment: а ещё лучше — задайте новый вопрос, чтобы объяснение основ попало в базу знаний и приносило бы пользу и другим новичкам.

Comment: в общем.я сделал все по инструкции как вы написали это раз.
все успешно .окей.
но.что еще мне нужно сделать какие танцы с бубном чтоб я мог спокойно запускать .py скрипты ?какие еще настройки надо?если есть докусментация дайте документацию буду очень признателен.ибо я уже облазил весь ине не нашел ничего дельного...неужели дела с питоном так сложно обстоят?что за волокита с его настройкой?...

Comment: прочитайте, пожалуйста, хотя бы этот [раздел](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/webservers.html#mod-python), а желательно весь документ. так уж вышло, что «питонисты» предпочитают интерфейсы типа cgi, а не запуск интерпретатора для отдельных файлов. из-за чего они вынуждены так делать, я лучше промолчу, чтобы лишний раз не обижать «священного питона». коротко говоря: mod-python заброшен. пользуйтесь *common gateway interface*-ами. наиболее развитый и активно поддерживаемый из них — wsgi.

Comment: и ещё раз повторю: на этом сайте не принято вести длинные дискуссии (для этого есть [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)). задавайте новые вопросы. это последний мой комментарий к этому вопросу.